# Mac OS X Application to Float a Window in Front of Others

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, window-manager

It would be nice if it was a button you could press on the top right that 'tacked' the currently selected window in front of all other windows permanently (until the button is pressed again).

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 7):

Not built into the OS, but you should take a look at [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) from [Infinite Labs](http://infinite-labs.net/).

Comment: I like its animation when setting a window to stay on top, however, it doesn't support almost any of the applications I use daily.

Comment: Afloat is getting negative reviews on MacUpdate with Mountain Lion and Mavericks. SnappyApp on the MacAppStore is a great free alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately Afloat is no longer available.  I can't find SnappyApp, so it seems to be unavailable too.  There's only a screenshot tool by that name.